# Weird badge (probably encoding issue)

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, tag-badges

I've just been granted a badge on http://russian.stackexchange.com, here's the link to the badge:

https://russian.stackexchange.com/help/badges/87/?userid=134

It looks to me like this:

> [image]

The link on the badge says https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%3f%3f%3f%3f%3f%3f%3f%3f%3f%3f

and just redirects to all questions page.

Comment: Yup, most likely encoding issue, with the tag itself. Weird!

Comment: It is most likely the [`грамматика`](http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0) tag; it is the only tag that currently qualifies you for a bronze tag badge (20+ answers, 100+ score and at least 100 questions tagged overall). The number of questions marks matches the number of characters, at least.

Comment: It is interesting that today (2 days after the bage is granted according to this post) the hint says "awarded 9 hours ago". Looks like the bage gets reawarded each day, is it?

Comment: @Artemix: interesting. That'd explain why I couldn't see a reason why the OP was awarded that badge two days ago. He's been awarded that badge every day for a few days now then.

Comment: Keep working at it, and you'll soon be able to dupe-hammer any [??????????] question!

Comment: <Bad Yakov Smirnov joke>In Russia, you don't earn tags, tags earn you!</Bad Yakov Smirnov joke>

Answer (score 15):

Well, this is embarrassing. Even though our database was configured for full unicode, one of the tools we use to talk from the web-servers to the database was configured for non-unicode. That kinda means that any badges involving tags with unicode characters are most likely jacked. I'll get the mapping updated, then we'll see if we can unscramble the mess and fix the names.

Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: ??? ?????? ??????!

Comment: To clarify: this only affects "badge name" - not global

Comment: @MarcGravell - And "tag name" as well??

Comment: @hims056 you're going to have to be more specific; AFAIK there is no issue affecting tag names